# Parallel foreach vs. parallel apply in R?

Tags: r, performance, foreach, parallel-processing, vectorization

Which one is more efficient in which situations? Which one cannot work at all in certain situations?

I am trying to make some general code more efficient and am curious which one is better, because as far as I've seen, they cannot be used in conjunction.

For reference:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

foreach (i = list) %dopar% {
...
}
```

vs.

```
library(parallel)

parLapply(cl, X = list, fun = function)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind? You might check out [benchmarking and profiling your code](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html).

Comment: Some pro and cons can be found here: http://www.uio.no/english/services/it/research/hpc/courses/r/2013-04_parallel_r.pdf